# Define a Visio QuickInfo in DatadiagramML

Tags: xml, visio

My program is outputting a chart as a VDX file to be viewed with Microsoft Visio (2013). In Visio a Shape can have a QuickInfo which is like a tooltip. How can I add such a QuickInfo or any other tooltip for a shape in the VDX file? VDX uses the XML schema DatadiagramML.

For reference I always use this [DatadiagramML schema overview](http://m8y.org/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_Reference_Schemas/Help/html/vixmlconSchema.htm), because Microsofts own references load too slowly. Either way I rarely find what I'm looking for there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution:

```
<Shape ID="12345" Type="Shape">
    ...
    <Misc ID="12346">
        <Comment ID="12347">The tooltip text!</Comment>
    </Misc>
</Shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as a QuickInfo, but it works, albeit a bit more inconveniently than a QuickInfo. The SmartTag is like a menu that pops up next to a shape and can show a tooltip text when hovering over it. Because I only need the tooltip this menu is actually empty.

```
<Shape ID="12345" Type="Shape">
    ...
    <SmartTagDef ID="12346">
        <Description ID="12347">The tooltip text!</Description>
    </SmartTagDef>
</Shape>
```

It's less convenient because you have to hover twice, first over the shape to see the menu button, then over the menu button to see the tooltip.